# wait 3 seconds, then do next task. inside map

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a list of usernames, which are basically accounts

```
let users = [
"user1","user2","user3","user4","user5","user6","user7"
]
```

```
users.map(async (user, i) => {
   console.log(user, i)
   let res = await sendmessage(user)
   if(res) {
     console.log("Message Sent to: " + user)
   }
})
```

What should happen, is it wait 3 seconds, then send message, then wait 3 seconds, then send message, but what actually is happening.
=> `console.log(user, i)` it executes this all at once,
I don't understand what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Share the definition of `sendmessage` function with use, please.

Comment: My best guess without seeing the `sendmessage` function is that you are creating a 3 second timeout there but it's getting created at once for every user so it all fires together after 3 seconds.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `map` - you're not returning anything, and `map` returns a new transformed array. `forEach` or a `for/of` is probably what you want.

Comment: map is wrong tool for this job. Sort of like using a hammer to open a window. It sort of works, but there is a better way.

Comment: The main issue here is understanding the difference between .map(), .forEach() or something different but fit for the job. [Read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map doesn't give any guarantee on sequential execution because each "iteration" doesn't know when the previous one will end.

The easiest way to achieve the desired result is to change `map` to `for...of`.
So your code would looks like this:

```js
const users = [
"user1","user2","user3","user4","user5","user6","user7"
] 

for (const user of users){
   console.log(user)
   const res = await sendmessage(user)
   if(res) {
     console.log("Message Sent to: " + user)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an asynchronous for loop with a wait function.

```js
const wait = async (ms) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  })
}

const users = [
  "user1","user2","user3","user4","user5","user6","user7"
];


for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
  const user = users[i];
  let res = await sendmessage(user)
  if(res) {
    console.log("Message Sent to: " + user)
  }
  await wait(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Async await concept and callback functions does not quite go together

since you don't return any data use an ordinary loop and your promises work as you intend them to work.

```
for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
    let user = users[i];
    let res = await sendmessage(user)
    if(res) {
      console.log("Message Sent to: " + user)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally for something like this, I would use a queue type of system and not mess with async/await or multiple timeouts.

```js
let users = [
"user1","user2","user3","user4","user5","user6","user7"
]



const sendMessage = (users, message, delay) => {

  const remaining = users.slice();
  
  const send = () => {
    const user = remaining.shift();  
    console.log(message, user);
    
    if (remaining.length) {
      setTimeout(send, delay);
    }
  }
  
  send();
}

sendMessage(users, "hello", 1000);
```

Comment: `users.slice()` or just `[...users]`